# How to create unique index for each player MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this!

```
 T1       
 Name Surname     Team
 John   Fire      Team1
 Mike   Ice       Team2
 Don    Grass     Team3
 John   Fire      Team4
 Jake   Finger    Team1
```

I want to **create** and **add** to this table column named ID!

ID would consist of:

'first letter of Name'+

'first letter of Surname'+

'-'+

Number automatically increasing if there have been same first letters before!

It would look like this!

```
 T1       
   ID   Name   Surname     Team
  JF-1  John    Fire       Team1
  MI-1  Mike     Ice       Team2
  DG-1  Don    Grass       Team3
  JF-1  John    Fire       Team4
  JF-2  Jake    Finger     Team1
```

What i need to add to this code?

```
#LAST TRY

create table T1 (
Name varchar(45),
Surname varchar(45),
Team varchar(45));

insert into T1(Name,Surname,Team) values ( 'John','Fire','Team1'),   ('Mike','Ice','Team2'),
('Don','Grass','Team3'),('John','Fire','Team4'),('Jake','Finger','Team1');

select * from T1;
```

Comment: Where do you expect those IDs to come from?

Comment: First letter of first name+first letter of last name+"-"+alphabetical order will determine the numerical value after the dash.  Ex. 15 names before John Smith = JS-16.  @Marcis - Have you tried at all to do this yourself besides create a table with random names/teams in it?

Comment: Sorry I asked wrong I want to create this ID by my self, but i dont know how!

Comment: Are you sure you want that index? What if John David and Joe Dirt were in the same team 1?

Comment: They might correct me if I'm wrong but team number seems to be completely independent of creating an ID for this.  The example tends to make you believe that's the case but look at the way "MI-1  Mike     Ice       Team2" still is MI-1.

Comment: @Spade I want that number to be given automatically!

Comment: @MikeS yes that is right!

Comment: That is interesting. So if there are four people John David, Joe Dirt, Michael Jackson and Michelle Joseph, John David and Joe Dirt should automatically be assigned to team 1 and Michael Jackson and Michelle Joseph automatically in team 2? Is that right?

Comment: No they just have to have different ID!

Comment: Don't do this. :-(

Comment: @Strawberry Why exactly?

Comment: Because it serves no purpose.

Comment: Adding a column like this looks like a really bad idea. It looks to me like the problems that this potentially creates are greater than whatever problem this is intended to solve. (Is there a even a problem that this solves?) How will a value be assigned when a new row is inserted to the table? If all rows for a given player are deleted from the table, will there be a mechanism that prevents that ID value from being reused? Will the same ID value be used if the same player is re-inserted? Or. for a different player? If a player's last name changes,will the ID also have to change?

Comment: Here is the thing! I understand what you are saying, but  today is 7 day of using MySQL WorkBench and MySQL or any SQL ever! Anyhow! For tables and database that i have to create for one of my studies this thing would solve a major problem for me!

Comment: @spencer7593 Can you solve this problem despite your negative opinion?

Comment: I'm positive there's a solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve. But adding this wacky ID column is *not* the solution to whatever problem that is. I don't understand your data model. But it doesn't look to be normalized. (It looks to me like "player" should be an *entity* in your model.) I could solve the problem, yes. But I would solve the *actual* problem, doing it the right way. Not by helping you create more problems by implementing a harebrained scheme.

Comment: @spencer7593  I have been given a table that looks like this http://imgur.com/xUhrV43         And i need to modify it to first 1NF  and it must have a new column that specifies only personal player data!

Comment: Looks like the table you've been given is a conglomeration of several entities: Player/Person. Team. TeamMember. Looks like this is table that they would give you for an exercise in normalization. **3NF**. Every attribute is dependent on the key, the *whole* key and *nothing* but the key. So help me Codd.  Seems to me like you should have a Player/person table. In that table, the unique identifier could serve as the PRIMARY KEY of the table. (Adding a screwball non-unique ID in some other table is *not* the relational approach to fixing the problem.)

Comment: Some potential problems that need to be addressed if you are intent on adding a screwball ID column. Is there a constraint in the database that prevents the same player from being assigned two different ID values? Or, a constraint that prevents the same ID value from being assigned to two different players? In addition to the original population of the new ID column, seems like you need to implement some kind of scheme that prevents these types of data anomalies from occurring, when rows are inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: In the end I need to have  a database that will have a 3NF and it will automatically update all tables in 3NF from a file that is in CSV format! One specification is that there can only be one Column that looks like ID and is specified for Person identification, in all tables!  Its not my rules , but teachers! Why? Do not ask me!

Comment: This question has been edited so much from its original form that my original answer has become irrelevant and gets downvotes. I am removing it - glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic approach for Id creation :

```
select * from(
select substring(Name,1,1), substring(Surname,1,1),
row_number() over (partition by Name,Surname order by Team)) from t1;
```

Will check syntax and expand.

Approach : Select first letter from first name, second letter from second name, and then based on grouping of name and surname, decide the number to be inserted.

EDIT :
 Try this as an implementation for MySQL.

```
select concat(concat(concat(SUBSTRING(NAME,1,1),SUBSTRING(SURNAME,1,1)),'-'),num) AS ID,
NAME,SURNAME,TEAM from

                            (SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @customer_no = SUBSTRING(NAME,1,1) and @customer2 = SUBSTRING(SURNAME,1,1)
        THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS num,
    @customer_no:=SUBSTRING(NAME,1,1) as CustomerNumber,
    @customer2 :=  SUBSTRING(SURNAME,1,1) as Customer2,
    @team := team                         
    team,name,surname
FROM
    T1 order by SUBSTRING(NAME,1,1), SUBSTRING(SURNAME,1,1),TEAM) as final;
```

Phew!! http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ is the reference link. But really MySQL!! Why can't you just give us basic analytic functions!!

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edb8b2/7

Comment: Learning 1 : row_number() doesnt exist in mysql

Comment: Yes, it won't, currently. Because I am an Oracle DB person, and row_number doesn't exist in mysql. Searching for alternatives.

Comment: @Marcus, This code purposely generates a JF-3, because I felt the IDs have to be unique. In your example, there are two JF-1s. Just inform if you want as-is. Hint : If yes, the game in order by moves to full names instead of substrings.

Comment: this code you wrote is good one, but yeah I want that in table there are two JF-1s!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the table you were given is a conglomeration of several entities.

Entity Relationship Modeling is the *key* to database design.

An *entity* is a person, place, thing, concept or event that can be uniquely identified, is important to the enterprise, and we can store information about.

Identify the *relationships* between the entities, and the cardinalities.

A "player" is a member of zero, one or more "teams"
A "team" consists of zero, one more "players"

Identify the candidate keys for the entity. Identify which attributes belong to which entities.

A "player" has one "date of birth".
A "player" has one "first name" and one "last name".

You should strive to get your data model to third normal form, before you implement a physical design. (Denormalize where needed for performance, but do not skip the step of getting to 3NF first. Before you implement.)

Once your model is in 3NF, then propose an implementation starting with a separate table for each entity.

As an example table definition for the Player/person entity, adding a surrogate key as the primary key:

```
create table player 
( id         int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment comment 'PK'
, surname    varchar(30)  comment 'last name'
, givname    varchar(30)  comment 'first name'
, dob        date         comment 'date of birth'
, UNIQUE KEY player_UX1 (surname, givname)
) engine=innodb
;
```

---

```
create table team
( id         int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment comment 'PK'
, team_name  varchar(50)
, mascot     varchar(100)
, ...
, UNIQUE KEY team_UX1 (team_name)
) engine=innodb;
```

Ignoring any temporal requirements, implement a many-to-many relationship between "player" and "team" as a *relationship* table, with foreign keys that refer to each table...

```
create table current_team_member
( team_id      int unsigned not null comment 'FK, ref team.id'
, player_id    int unsigned not null comment 'FK, ref player.id'
, date_joined  date
, ...
, PRIMARY KEY (team_id, player_id, ... )
, CONSTRAINT FK_current_team_member_team
    FOREIGN KEY (team_id)  REFERENCES team(id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_current_team_member_player
    FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES player(id) 
) engine=innodb;
```

---

```
INSERT INTO player (givname, surname, dob, ...)
SELECT ...        AS givname
     , ...        AS surname
     , MIN(...)   AS dob
  FROM conglomeration_of_a_jumbled_mess t 
 GROUP BY givname, surname
 ORDER BY givname, surname
 ;

INSERT INTO team (team_name, ...
SELECT t.team_name 
     , ...
  FROM conglomeration_of_a_jumbled_mess t 
 GROUP BY t.team_name
 ORDER BY t.team_name
 ;
```

Comment: I am not very god at English ! If I understand correctly you are saying that table that would look like that is no go ?And I better just give every row a unique ID?

Comment: Each *player* should have a unique key. Each *team* should have a unique key. It can be a composite key, or it can be a single column. In many cases, we find that a surrogate id as a PRIMARY KEY satisfies several desirable properties of a PRIMARY KEY...   non-null (assigned on every row), unique (no duplicate values), simple (single column with short native datatype), anonymous (doesn't carry any meaningful information), immutable (assigned once and it doesn't change), et al. (1NF and 2NF don't even make sense to me. Give me those and all I see is models that aren't 3NF.)

Comment: I would *not* include the first letter of a players first and last name in the primary key. (If we do that, when the player's name changes, then there will be desire to change the value of the primary key, because "the first two characters are from the players name". That violates the desirable property of the surrogate key being *anonymous*. I don't want  a surrogate key to be dependent on values of attributes of the entity. Just a plain old simple meaningless integer works for me.

Comment: Ok , now I get It! For ID better use data that cannot change or  is just randomly given and has no attachment to another values! Right?

Comment: Personally, I think those academic exercises of converting a jumbled mess to first normal form, and then to second normal form, before getting to third normal form are confusing. Mostly because those intermediate forms are still *wrong*. To me, going through the exercise of entity relationship modeling, asking appropriate questions, discovering what the entities are, the relationships between them, what the candidate keys are gets us to a workable model much faster. It also lets us discover requirements that are "hidden" by the currently flawed implementation.

Comment: I agree , but it is just what teacher asked me and that is why this question arose! :)

Comment: Did the teacher specify using the initial letters of the first and last name, and to re-use integer values? Perhaps the purpose of the exercise is to have you learn some of the reasons *why* you don't want to do that. For the solution from *I_am_Batman*, what happens when the rows for JF-1 are deleted. And you insert another user... Jack Frost, Team5. What value would be assigned to that new player? Would you get a value of JF-3, or would it generate JF-2? (i.e. one that is already assigned?)

Comment: ID must consist of letters and numbers- that was the specification! I think he wanted us to learn how to create ID that consists of letters and numbers! I do not know how to create random letter so I thought that first letters are gonna work, because number will be one that changes! HOW ACTUALLY CAN YOU CREATE A RANDOM LETTER AT MySQL?

Answer (score -2):

Given the new information you posted, you aren't actually creating a table with unique fields. What you are doing is creating a table where a given person can show up N times, and so they need an identifier that is totally unique to them (in case of, say, two people with the same first and last name). Without consolidating the table down so that each player only appears once, with all of their teams enumerated on that line, you'll need to simply define these IDs upon insert. So,

```
create table T1 (
ID varchar(4),
Name varchar(45),
Surname varchar(45),
Team varchar(45));
```

And then modify your inserts to have the ID included:

```
insert into T1(ID,Name,Surname,Team) values ( 'JF-1','John','Fire','Team1')
```

and so on.

Comment: The question has, unfortunately, changed.

Comment: @3nails4you IF i will write UNIQUE (ID) it will show error because ID's are not unique for that column!

Comment: If the values aren't going to be unique, then you simply don't need to add the unique constraint at the end. I added in the unique because your question asked about how to create a unique index.

Comment: Ah, I see now - the same person could be on multiple teams. In that case, you certainly don't need to add in the unique qualifier for the ID field.

Comment: @3nails4you  But i do not want to insert it manually I want that it is created for me!

Comment: But you are already inserting the name manually, correct? If you have some code that handles the inserts for you, then I would recommend writing a solution there (select from the database where ID rlike [FIRST_INITIAL][LAST_INITIAL] and then, if any are returned and this is a new entry, increment the number then use that). Otherwise, if you need this to be auto-generated on a manual insert, the only way that I know to do that is to simply use an auto-incremented integer, with no initials in your ID, and consolidate each entry down to one row.